# Layout for iphone 4, 4s and 5 on same storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, autolayout, iphone-5

I'm making an app for iphone. My layout can be the same for iphone 4, 4s, and 5 but for the iphone 4 and 4s the only thing that change is space between buttons. I finished my app and i arrange all storyboard to run well on iphone 5. Now i only have to tell that when the app running on iphone 4 and 4s i have to change the space between the buttons in some views to get all buttons inside screen. How i can do this? I can use auto layout i think but i dont use this. Its possible to help me? I do the things right, doing the design first for iphone 5 and now adapt for iphone 4 or im doing the things in the wrong way.

Regards

Comment: why you need to change and add space between buttons because as far as i know the screen height and width is same for 4 and 4s...and 4s is just a retina display so it has clear vision no extra space difference in 4 vs 4s.

Comment: i have to change space between buttons for iphone4s layout because i layout my app for a 4" screen like display of iphone 5

Comment: okay so what you need? do you need a condition to check for wether its iphone5 or iphone4/4s?

Comment: See my comment to the other answer.. Thanks for Ur help

Answer (score 1):

The IOS6 autolayout it's still a bit "wild" and it will also disable the IOS5 compatibility.
If you don't use autolayout, you can still set some rules in storyboard at size inspector, like tide you buttons to the top or the bottom of the view, so you can control where they go when the screen shrinks.

A better way is to add subviews to your view, and allow the subviews to shrink and expand (also @ size inspector in storyboard). Then add your buttons to those subviews, tide them to the top, bottom, or let them untied/free if they are placed symmetrically inside the subview.

You can simulate quickly with the form factor button in storyboard (right-down corner) to see where the buttons go when you switch the sizes.

These methods require zero lines of code, but more work with the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's mu first app/game and what i want is the best way to do the same app, with same design adapt their layout for iPhone 4,4s and 5 for example decreasing the space left between buttons, between the top and the start of first view etc... In the future the app will be available to the iPad and i want to do the same with the iPad storyboard to make the app compatible with iPad mini and iPad. What i can do and In the best way? Using or not autolayout (i read that is better using autolayout) but i cant find good tutorials or information to make a effective good universal app

Comment: Autolayout it's a strong feature, unfortunately the way the priorities are managed it's difficult to be understand. There is hope with IOS7/xcode5 that autolayout feature will be improved. Regarding iPad support, the best is to create a new storyboard or xib only for iPad, and if the functionality and content of the viewcontroller is the same as on iPhone (and only the design/arrangement is changed), you can simply link your new storyboard outlets with the existing iPhone code.